# Iterate through An Array To Create New Class (JS)

Tags: javascript, class, for-loop

I'm working on using Classes with JavaScript and am not sure how to move forward. I think what I have below performs the for loop successfully, but I'm stuck on how to console.log the newly created Resources.

My goal is to create cards for them using Bootstrap or Foundation then appending them to the body.

My code below:

```
var ResourcesArray = ["Blacksmith", "Farm", "Gold", "Herb", "Quarry", "Vineyard", "Wood"]

class Resource {
    constructor(name, amount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount
    }
    
    add() {
        this.amount + 1
    }
    subtract() {
        this.amount - 1
    }
    trade() {
        console.log(this.name)
    }
}

function createResourceCards() {
    for (i = 0; i < ResourcesArray.length; i++) {
        new Resource(ResourcesArray[i], 0)
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can save the instances created in the loop in an array so that you can reference them later. `arr.push(new Resource(ResourcesArray[i], 0));`. `arr` is the array that can be defined in the `createResourceCards` function

Comment: *I'm stuck on how to console.log...* There are some excellent youtube vids on tracing and debugging using Chrome dev tools, such as [Debugging Javascript Beginner to Advanced in one video](https://youtu.be/-q1z8BPFItw)

Comment: Also note that `this.amount + 1` inside `add` method does not change `this.amount`. You need to save the result --> `this.amount += 1`. Same mistake in `subtract` method. Change it to ---> `this.amount -= 1`.

Comment: override `Resource.toString()` to display all properties of the object. Then it is simply `console.log(thisResource);`

Answer (score 0):

The expression `new Foo()` [returns the instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) that was just created. Just store it in a variable:

```
function createResourceCards() {
    for (i = 0; i < ResourcesArray.length; i++) {
        let res = new Resource(ResourcesArray[i], 0);
        console.log(res);
    }
}
```

However you probably want the function to return the new resource cards. For this purpose you should make an array and push them all into the array as suggested in comments on the question. However there is also a shortcut to do this: [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), demonstrated below.

```js
const ResourcesArray = ["Blacksmith", "Farm", "Gold", "Herb", "Quarry", "Vineyard", "Wood"]

class Resource {
    constructor(name, amount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount
    }
    
    add() {
        this.amount + 1
    }
    subtract() {
        this.amount - 1
    }
    trade() {
        console.log(this.name)
    }
}

function createResourceCards() {
    return ResourcesArray.map(res => new Resource(res, 0));
}

let resources = createResourceCards();
console.log(resources);
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you use `new Resource()` it returns the newly created class so you can either store them in an array, object or map. Object/Map with the name as the key would likely be most useful

```
let resourceClasses = new Map()
function createResourceCards() {
    for (i = 0; i < ResourcesArray.length; i++) {
        let newResource = new Resource(ResourcesArray[i], 0)
        resourceClasses.set(ResourcesArray[i], newResource);
    }

}
```

Then with this newly created Map you can get the resource classes by their name

```
resourceClasses.has("Blacksmith");
 // Returns true/false if you have a key by this name
resourceClasses.get("Blacksmith"); 
// This returns the value stored in Blacksmith which is your new Class
```

EDIT: As @Klaycon mentions you can also use .map() as a useful way to iterate over an array and create a new array based of running logic for each element